# taggedpdf error in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

My tags are follows (Thanks to `Ulrike`):

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase} \DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{uncompress, %for the test, to check the pdf
             activate-mc}
\begin{document}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Figure,alttext={my figure}}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\label{fig:img.jpg}
\tagmcend
\end{document}
```

I got the below error using `Overleaf`:

```
<recently read> \DocumentMetadata 
l.1 ...{pdfmanagement-testphase} \DocumentMetadata
```

How can I fix this? Please advise...

Comment: Overleaf has an older latex. There you probably can use `\DeclareDocumentMetadata`. But be aware that tagpdf is an experimental package and part of a developing project.  It is not really meant for normal production and stable systems like overleaf which are typically older. If you get other errors there, you won't get any help apart from "update to a newer system".

Comment: Hi there, thanks for asking, Tom from Overleaf Support here. I'm afraid I can't give a much better advice than what Ulrike says. I can just clairfy that we aim at releasing the new TeX Live during Q3 each year, and we freeze around June, so whichever package version is on CTAN in June will be in Overleaf a few months later. Hope this helps clarify!